# Deferred Screenspace Decals in Metal

Tags: ios, metal, metalkit

Trying to create deferred screenspace decals rendering in Metal by following [this article](https://martindevans.me/game-development/2015/02/27/Drawing-Stuff-On-Other-Stuff-With-Deferred-Screenspace-Decals/). Though can't seem to figure it out...

These are bounds of the decal...

[image: decal bounds]

Actual result...

[image: result]

### Potential issue

So apparently it doesn't think that the decal is intersecting the mesh, I'm sampling the depth value correctly, but then when calculating the actual position the the pixel in 3D space something doesn't add up.

### Code

```
vertex VertexOut vertex_decal(
    const VertexIn in [[ stage_in ]],
    constant DecalVertexUniforms &uniforms [[ buffer(2) ]]
) {
    VertexOut out;

    out.position = uniforms.projectionMatrix * uniforms.viewMatrix * uniforms.modelMatrix * in.position;
    out.viewPosition = (uniforms.viewMatrix * uniforms.modelMatrix * in.position).xyz;
    out.normal = uniforms.normalMatrix * in.normal;
    out.uv = in.uv;
    
    return out;
}

fragment float4 fragment_decal(
    const VertexOut in [[ stage_in ]],
    constant DecalFragmentUniforms &uniforms [[ buffer(3) ]],
    depth2d<float, access::sample> depthTexture [[ texture(0) ]]
) {
    constexpr sampler textureSampler (mag_filter::nearest, min_filter::nearest);

    float2 resolution = float2(
        depthTexture.get_width(),
        depthTexture.get_height()
    );
    
    float2 textureCoordinate = in.position.xy / resolution;
    float depth = depthTexture.sample(textureSampler, textureCoordinate);
    
    float3 viewRay = in.viewPosition * (uniforms.farClipPlane / in.viewPosition.z);

    float3 viewPosition = viewRay * depth;
    float3 worldPositon = (uniforms.inverseViewMatrix * float4(viewPosition, 1)).xyz;
    float3 objectPositon = (uniforms.inverseModelMatrix * float4(worldPositon, 1)).xyz;
    
    float distX = 0.5 - abs(objectPositon.x);
    float distY = 0.5 - abs(objectPositon.y);
    float distZ = 0.5 - abs(objectPositon.z);

    if(distX > 0 && distY > 0 && distZ > 0) {
        return float4(1, 0, 0, 0.5);
    } else {
        discard_fragment();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Made a bit of a progress, now it at least renders something, it clips the decal box correctly once its outside of some mesh, but the parts on the mesh are still not completely correct.. to be exact it also renders sides of the box that are overlapping with the mesh under the decal (you can see it on the image below as the red there is a bit darker)

[image: depth issue]

And to add more details, the depthTexture is passed from previous "pass" so it only contains the icosphere on it, and the decal cube shader doesn't write to the depthTexture, just reads from it.

and depth stencil is defined as...

```
let stencilDescriptor = MTLDepthStencilDescriptor()
stencilDescriptor.depthCompareFunction = .less
stencilDescriptor.isDepthWriteEnabled = false
```

and render pipeline is defined as...

```
let renderPipelineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
renderPipelineDescriptor.vertexDescriptor = vertexDescriptor

renderPipelineDescriptor.vertexFunction = vertexLibrary.makeFunction(name: "vertex_decal")
renderPipelineDescriptor.fragmentFunction = fragmentLibrary.makeFunction(name: "fragment_decal")

if let colorAttachment = renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0] {
    colorAttachment.pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
    colorAttachment.isBlendingEnabled = true
    colorAttachment.rgbBlendOperation = .add
    colorAttachment.sourceRGBBlendFactor = .sourceAlpha
    colorAttachment.destinationRGBBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
}

renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[1].pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
renderPipelineDescriptor.depthAttachmentPixelFormat = .depth32Float
```

so the current issue is that it discards only pixels that are out of the mesh that its being projected on, instead of all pixels that are "above" the surface of the icosphere

### New Shader Code

```
fragment float4 fragment_decal(
    const VertexOut in [[ stage_in ]],
    constant DecalFragmentUniforms &uniforms [[ buffer(3) ]],
    depth2d<float, access::sample> depthTexture [[ texture(0) ]]
) {
    constexpr sampler textureSampler (mag_filter::nearest, min_filter::nearest);

    float2 resolution = float2(
        depthTexture.get_width(),
        depthTexture.get_height()
    );
        
    float2 textureCoordinate = in.position.xy / resolution;
    float depth = depthTexture.sample(textureSampler, textureCoordinate);
    
    float3 screenPosition = float3(textureCoordinate * 2 - 1, depth);
    float4 viewPosition = uniforms.inverseProjectionMatrix * float4(screenPosition, 1);
    float4 worldPosition = uniforms.inverseViewMatrix * viewPosition;
    float3 objectPosition = (uniforms.inverseModelMatrix * worldPosition).xyz;
    
    if(abs(worldPosition.x) > 0.5 || abs(worldPosition.y) > 0.5 || abs(worldPosition.z) > 0.5) {
        discard_fragment();
    } else {
        return float4(1, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's definitely not enough code here to figure out what's going on. Also, are binding the depth texture you are rendering into or is it a separate one?

Comment: JustSomeGuy, edited the question to add more details, besides making some more progress that is also mentioned there... is this enough? thanks! as for the depth texture, its the depth texture of the icosphere, the decal shader doesn't write to the depthTexture

Comment: What I mean is, is the depth texture bound as depth attachment while also being read from?

Comment: yes, its bound also as depth attachment

Comment: You can't do that in metal, sampling from a texture that is attached is undefined behavior. It may work on some machines, but it will fail on others in unpredictable ways.

Comment: In general, in deferred, if you are gonna need a depth texture (and you are gonna need it for basically anything), you create a separate `r32float` texture that you write out the depth to while outputting your gbuffer.

Comment: Ah, good to know, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally managed to get it to work properly, so the final shader code is...

the issues that the latest shader had were...

- Flipped Y axis on screenPosition
- Not converting the objectPosition to NDC space (`localPosition`)

```
fragment float4 fragment_decal(
    const VertexOut in [[ stage_in ]],
    constant DecalFragmentUniforms &uniforms [[ buffer(3) ]],
    depth2d<float, access::sample> depthTexture [[ texture(0) ]],
    texture2d<float, access::sample> colorTexture [[ texture(1) ]]
) {
    constexpr sampler depthSampler (mag_filter::linear, min_filter::linear);

    float2 resolution = float2(
        depthTexture.get_width(),
        depthTexture.get_height()
    );
        
    float2 depthCoordinate = in.position.xy / resolution;
    float depth = depthTexture.sample(depthSampler, depthCoordinate);
    
    float3 screenPosition = float3((depthCoordinate.x * 2 - 1), -(depthCoordinate.y * 2 - 1), depth);
    float4 viewPosition = uniforms.inverseProjectionMatrix * float4(screenPosition, 1);
    float4 worldPosition = uniforms.inverseViewMatrix * viewPosition;
    float4 objectPosition = uniforms.inverseModelMatrix * worldPosition;
    float3 localPosition = objectPosition.xyz / objectPosition.w;
    
    if(abs(localPosition.x) > 0.5 || abs(localPosition.y) > 0.5 || abs(localPosition.z) > 0.5) {
        discard_fragment();
    } else {
        float2 textureCoordinate = localPosition.xy + 0.5;
        float4 color = colorTexture.sample(depthSampler, textureCoordinate);
        
        return float4(color.rgb, 1);
    }
}
```

The final results look like this (red are pixels that are kept, blue pixels are discarded)...

[image: final result]